# how to use java generics type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

whats the difference between

```
public static <T> double sums(Collection<T extends Number> numbers) {}
```

and this

```
public static <T extends Number> double sums(Collection<T> numbers) {}
```

and this

```
public static double sums(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) {}
```

and this

```
public static <T> double sums(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) {}
```

i get that we mention type parameter `<T>` before return type if we are using generics for only one method.and we can use the type parameter T here since its declared as classes type parameter(**`public class generics<T extends Integer  >{}`**). and i dont quite  understand the difference between them. especially first and last.
im getting compile error on first statement, and no error on last statement. why i need to use `?` wildcard at first statement ? and may i know how having static keyword affects this method declaration?

edit: Im not using the type inside method so type parameter `<T>` or `<?>` should be functionally same. im using only one parameterized type argument which according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card) should be same even if we use wildcards there but im getting compile error when i use type parameter .

Comment: The last variant doesn't use `T` at all.....?

Comment: Your first does not compile.

Comment: This will be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html Please try to find similar questions and other help from Google before asking questions, Happy coding!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generic method parameter type inside brackets vs. outside brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448884/java-generic-method-parameter-type-inside-brackets-vs-outside-brackets)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card

Comment: @SilvioMayolo according to that question both has same functionality, but OP seems to have compile issues on first code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break them each down.

1. This is nonsense. Don't do it. There's a reason it won't compile.
2. Here, we're defining a generic function `sums`. Our function can be called with a collection containing elements of some specific numerical type.
3. This is similar to (2). More on that below.
4. This is a strange version of (3). Don't do this either; you've just declared a type parameter and not used it, so there's really no point.

Now, (2) and (3) are very similar. When we use `?` as a type parameter, we're essentially saying "this can be whatever, but I don't particularly care what its value is". On the other hand, when we explicitly use `T`, we can use that type parameter to do other things. It's a type-level variable.

```
public static <T extends Number> double sums(Collection<T> numbers) {
  for (T arg : numbers) {
    // Do something with arg
  }
}
```

We can iterate over the structure, and our `arg` is well-typed since we know what sort of thing is in the collection. With (3), we lose some information.

```
public static double sums(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) {
  for (Number arg : numbers) {
    // Do something with arg
  }
}
```

We know `numbers` contains numbers of *some specific type*, but we don't know what it is, so we have to fall back to the more general but still safe `Number`.

Comment: instead of saying nonsense code you could have said why its nonsense. and also the reason why it wont compile.

Comment: With 3 and 4, you cannot add anything to the collection, since the type of elements is specific but unknown.

Comment: the question is not related to PECS.im simply asking about the syntactic usage of type parameter and wildcard.

Comment: @MCEmperor: "With 3 and 4, you cannot add anything to the collection" Well you *can* pass it to another method with signature #2, which *can* add stuff to it (although it can only add elements from the collection to itself, since it doesn't know what `T` is), so it can, indirectly, do anything #2 can.

Comment: @newacct Sure, in that way it's possible. And one can also simply typecast it.